# Why do I need a default case in this Swift switch?

Tags: swift

I believe the following Swift code should compile, but the compiler errors with the `Switch must be exhaustive` error. Is there a special property about `Int` subtraction that allows a possible result outside of "greater than 0", "less than 0", and "equal to 0"?

```
public enum MediaOrientation {
    case portrait
    case landscape
    case square

    init(width: Int, height: Int) {
        switch width - height {
        case let x where x == 0: self = .square
        case let x where x < 0: self = .portrait
        case let x where x > 0: self = .landscape
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: "Even if you think you know your cases will always be executed, you need to have the default: to fall back on." https://medium.com/ios-os-x-development/switch-cases-in-swift-29366716242d it's just the way it is.

Comment: Compilers normally do static analysis to prevent obvious problems like making sure all cases are used. 

They usually don't perform semantic checking to understand your logic as it can slow down compile time and its hard to be accurate all the time.

 In these cases you can just add empty default case and should be fine.

Comment: `self = width < height ? .portrait : width > height ? .landscape : .square`

Comment: @LeoDabus I prefer the switch, tbh. It's waaaay more characters, but it almost reads llike a dictionary